# How to remove 'connection to xx.xxx.xx.xxx closed' message?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -t $SSH "
    some
    commands
"
```

Where is the  'connection to xx.xxx.xx.xxx closed' message coming from? I can't stop it even with result=`ssh ...`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is coming from SSH.  You see it because you gave the `-t` switch, which forces SSH to allocate a [pseudo-terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) for the connection.  Traditionally, SSH displays that message to make it clear that you are no longer interacting with the shell on the remote host, which is normally only a question when SSH has a pseudo-terminal allocated.

Answer (score 60):

if you add `-o LogLevel=QUIET` to the SSH command line, that message should disappear:

```
ssh -o LogLevel=QUIET -t $SSH "
      some 
      commands
"
```

You can also add it to the `~/.ssh/config` file as a line saying `LogLevel QUIET`

Comment: This should be the accpeted answer to me

Comment: Perhaps this answer should be accepted!

Comment: Making SSH quiet also removes the useful host key fingerprint. I'd like to remove the "connection to XXXX closed" part (or remove XXXX from that message)

Comment: Or use `ssh -q` as already mentioned in other comments.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a pretty old question but it pops up in searches.

A better answer is here: [How to hide or edit a message on closure of a ssh ,when ssh was handled using interact in expect script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32329664/4086928).

Basically, use the `ssh -q` option - it worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 6):

As Fran mentioned, this is coming about because of the -t switch. You can hide the message by appending:

```
 2> /dev/null
```

Your code would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -t $SSH "
    some
    commands
" 2> /dev/null
```

This redirects STDERR to /dev/null. Keep in mind all error messages that may be raised will also be redirected to /dev/null and so will be hidden from view.

Comment: There is problem here, if i want to log the output, this will not help. But other than that its good.

Comment: @indianwebdevil actually this is not going to hide the output of the script (nor the stderr from the remote commands you run), just your local stderr stream (basically other ssh warnings/errors you may get).

Answer (score 1):

The use of '-q' or '-oLogLevel=quiet', or '2>/dev/null' is mentioned elsewhere, but those solutions will suppresses all the SSH error messages. It's better to see relevant errors, yet suppress the "Connection" message.
This example will show errors and suppress the "Connection" message (in Bash):

```
ssh -t -oLogLevel=error myhost mycommand 2> >(grep -v '^Connection to' 1>&2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not comment on Fran's answer which is the correct one.

Just wanted to add that your code fragment looks like a script, which means you are likely calling remote stuff which is not depending on an interactive screen (unlike for example `mc` or `top` which make little sense without a keyboard and a screen - you will therefore not use these programs in scripts).

So you are better off explicitly without a terminal. That means replace the -t flag with the -T flag. Longer syntax which I prefer in scripts to make them more self evident and readable would be: `-o 'RequestTTY no'` vs. `-o 'RequestTTY yes'`.

And while at that, forget the `-o LogLevel=QUIET` solution suggested by Leo - it hides error messages too. If your script faces some unfavourable circumstances, you will not understand what went wrong. In scripts you probably want to use `-o LogLevel=ERROR` - this suppresses the remote machine's banner if it has one, but lets error messages through.

Comment: I'm always flabbergasted, when seeing how cooperative answers, which lead with objective suggestions to an comprehensive solution are downvoted. I set it to ERROR for my interactive configuration and the message is gone, while still receiving errors. Answer upvoted.